# Determine if the current user is above the record owner in the role hierarchy

Tags: validation

I am looking to write a validation rule that prevents everyone from editing a record in a certain status, unless they are above the record owner in the role hierarchy.

So for example here is my fake hierarchy:

Role CEO -> Role Exec -> Role Drone

Once a drone has created a record and saved it as locked, the drone can not longer edit the record.

But the Exec or CEO can edit the record. Is this possible using a validation rule?

Comment: If the sharing model is private and access is granted using hierarchies, then by default only the owner and above can edit the record. If you want to prevent the owner, a validation rule can be added to that effect. As a result only someone higher than the Owner would be able to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot take away sharing access to the owner of the record, but you can prevent the owner from saving an edited record:  $User.Id <> OwnerId where $User is the current user. Everything else is sharing based.